# Only First Alarm is set on reboot, no matter time has passed or not(android)

Tags: android

I'm new to android and trying to create an event reminder app by reading some books and tutorials. Please excuse me if it is duplicate question but i searched on forum and couldn't get solution to my problem. Alarms get triggered properly when device is on. But when my device reboots in onreceive it reads all data from database and set all alarms by calling setreminder() method and then it fires first alarm no matter whether time has reached or not and will not show notification for any other alarm (although it must show for second and third one). i have added permission and receiver in manifest. This is my code
OnBootReceiver

```
    public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
       private static final String TAG = ComponentInfo.class.getCanonicalName();
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
       {
          ReminderManager reminderMgr = new ReminderManager(context);
          RemindersDbAdapter dbHelper = new RemindersDbAdapter(context);
          dbHelper.open();

          Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllReminders();
          if(cursor != null)
          {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int rowIdColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
            int dateTimeColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_DT);

            while(cursor.isAfterLast() == false)
            {
              Log.d(TAG, "Adding alarm from boot.");
              Log.d(TAG, "Row Id Column Index - " + rowIdColumnIndex);
              Log.d(TAG, "Date Time Column Index - " + dateTimeColumnIndex);
              Long rowId = cursor.getLong(rowIdColumnIndex);
              Log.d(TAG, "rowid - " + rowId);
              String dateTime = cursor.getString(dateTimeColumnIndex);
              Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
              SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(DisplayMessageActivity.DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
              try {
                java.util.Date date = format.parse(dateTime);
                Log.d(TAG, "Date- " + date);
                cal.setTime(date);
                reminderMgr.setReminder(rowId, cal);
                } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {

                Log.e("OnBootReceiver", e.getMessage(), e);

                }
             cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close() ;
           } 
         dbHelper.close();
         }
         }
         }
```

remindermanager

```
    public class ReminderManager
    {
      private static final String TAG = ComponentInfo.class.getCanonicalName();
      private Context mContext;
      private AlarmManager mAlarmManager;
      public ReminderManager(Context context)
      {
          mContext = context;
          mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
       }

       public void setReminder(Long taskId, Calendar when)
       {
           Log.d(TAG, "when: "+when);
           Log.d("remindermanage", "rowid: "+taskId);
           Intent i = new Intent(mContext, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
           i.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, (long)taskId);
           PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
           mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

1) use a database in broadcast receiver it's not a good idea, it would be better to start an intent service and do the work there;

2) you are calling setReminder in a loop but you are using the pending instance because you are using always 0 and FLAG_ONE_SHOOT. If you want to create multiple pending intents you need to create and pass to the method an unique id each time.

Comment: thank you so much!! I'l try to work out what u pointed out!! Should i create another method in intent service to set alarm, or should i pass unique id to this method only.